# swift: Keeping the ViewController in the exact same condition

Tags: ios, swift

In ViewController 1 I have a date picker and a text field. I have another ViewController that displays what you have entered in that date picker and text field. I have a ¨change¨ button that returns you to that first view controller, but as of now the text in the textfield and the date that the user has selected, is gone every time you close the app or click the ¨change¨ button.

How can i keep the text in the text field, and the selected date in the date picker.

I want the user to be able to change the information that has already been added.

Comment: you can temporarily save it by passing it between the view controllers!

Comment: show us how you are changing the view controllers,  you could be loading a new controller every time and not realize it

Answer (score 0):

Why not using NSUserDefault to make persist a String :

```
// save the text of the textfield
NSUserDefault.setValue(textField.text, forKey: "key")

// set the text of textfield to saved value
if let string = userDefault.valueForKey("key") as? String {
        textField.text = string
    }
```